# PHP Regex: Select all except last occurrence

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace all `\n`'s sans that final one with `\n\t` in order to nicely indent for a recursive function.

```
This
that
then
thar
these
them
```

should become:

```
This
    that
    then
    thar
    these
them
```

This is what I have: `preg_replace('/\n(.+?)\n/','\n\t$1\n',$var);`

It currently spits this out:

```
This
    that
then
thar
these
them
```

## Quick Overview:

Need to indent every line less the first and last line using regex, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: tried that: Unknown modifier 'g', that's why I'm confused.

Comment: It's not possible that that code produces that output.... [and it doesn't](http://codepad.org/f9SiMGm4).

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Your example clearly fails.

Comment: @Korvin: What? That's the OP's example. Of course it fails, or else he would not be here. I'm merely demonstrating that it fails in a different way to what the OP claimed.

Comment: Oh alright, I misinterpreted.

Comment: @Korvin: I just noticed that _you're_ the OP, so it's _your_ example. Bizarre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fixing a quotes issue, your output is *actually* like this:

```
This
    that
then
    thar
these
them
```

Use a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to stop that trailing `\n` from getting eaten by the search regex. Your "cursor" was already set beyond it so only every other line was being rewritten; your match "zones" overlapped.

```
echo preg_replace('/\n(.+?)(?=\n)/', "\n\t$1", $input);
//          newline-^  ^-text ^-lookahead ^- replacement
```

#### [Live demo.](http://codepad.org/5w5yukH4)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$var = preg_replace('/\n(?=.*?\n)/', "\n\t", $var);
```

See it working here: [ideone](http://ideone.com/2MzZE)

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/\n(.+?)(?=\n)/',"\n\t$1",$var);
```

Modified the second `\n` to be the lookahead `(?=\n)`, otherwise you'd run into issues with regex not recognizing overlapping matches.

http://ideone.com/1JHGY

Answer (score -1):

Let the downwoting begin, but why use regex for this?

```
<?php
$e = explode("\n",$oldstr);
$str = $e[count($e) - 1]; 
unset($e[count($e) - 1]);
$str = implode("\n\t",$e)."\n".$str;
echo $str;
?>
```

Actually, str_replace has a "count" parameter, but I just can't seem to get it to work with php 5.3.0 (found a bug report). This should work:

```
<?php
$count = substr_count($oldstr,"\n") - 1;
$newstr = str_replace("\n","\n\t",$oldstr,&$count);
?>
```

Comment: Why go through all that when a regex will let you do it in one line of code?

Comment: @AlanMoore Not to mention the regex can easily be applied to another language.