# Perl regular expression to remove all except last occurrence

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to use the command line "rename" to change some filenames that contain several periods. For example: `this.is.a.file.name.txt`

After looking around a bit I've found some examples that almost get me there, but I can't seem to get it to work as required. Needless to say, I'm a very green beginner with regex's.

I've tried this:

```
rename -v -n 's/\.(.+?)(?=\.)//' this.is.a.file.name.txt
```

Which results in this:

```
this.a.file.name.txt
```

I've tried to modify the examples found in the following resources, but I'm stuck.
[PHP Regex: Select all except last occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718905/php-regex-select-all-except-last-occurrence)
[Regex not replacing the last occurrence of a match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175859/regex-not-replacing-the-last-occurrence-of-a-match)

Comment: Could you provide a more clear example of what the input and desired output would be?  Are you trying to remove all but the file extension?

Comment: @willOEM Yes, that's correct, I want to keep just the file extension. So the desired result would be: `thisisafilename.txt`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regular expression is not quite right for a couple of reasons. First, the thing you're substituting the empty string for should be just the period, whereas you're matching from a period to everything that is the next period and removing that. Also, you're only doing it once.

The regular expression you want is `/\.(?=.*\.)//g`, which says match a period that is followed by a zero-width assertion of any number of characters and another period, and do that as many times as it can.

Comment: This works perfectly. I simply prepend this with "s" and receive this verification:
     `$ rename -n -v 's/\.(?=.*\.)//g' sdv.sdgs.hsdgh.sdg.sdf`

     `sdv.sdgs.hsdgh.sdg.sdf renamed as sdvsdgshsdghsdg.sdf`